# Condition of Convergence for recurrence relation!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am studying physics and mechanical engineering. I have to deal with a recurrence relation with:

$a_0=a$, 
$a_{n+1}=a_n+hf'(a_n)$, $f'(x_0)=0$, $h>0$

where $x_0$ is the unique critical point in interval $\mathbb{J}$ and $\forall{j}, a_j \in\mathbb{J}$.

In other words, one point is moved with distance proportional to the derivative on that point. At first it intuitively converges to the critical point $x_0$, but I recognized that it actually does not converge for some functions such as $f(x)=x^3$ or else. Can anyone tell me brief conditions for $f$ so that the limit of sequence converges to the critical point $x_0$, and give me a proof of why the sequence converges?

Comment: Since $h>0$, the recurrence is gradient ascent. Now, if $x_0$ is a local maxima, that is, $f^{''}(x_0) < 0$, then the recurrence should converge to $x_0$.

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 with $f(x)=-x^2$ and $h=1$, we still don't have convergence

Comment: If you are doing simulations, then your $h$ must be sufficiently small for the recurrence to converge. Large $h$ will lead to over-steps.

Comment: Take $a = -10$, $h = 0.1$ and $f(x) = -x^2$, the recurrence is converging to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between $x+hf'(x)$ and $y+hf'(y)$ is $(x-y)\cdot(1+hf''(\xi))$ for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$. Thus if 
If $$-2<hf''(x)<0$$ 
for all $x$, the recursion is a contraction and convergence is guaranteed.